# NestJS gRPC freezes for ~10-~15 seconds before accepting new requests

Tags: nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm testing out gRPC within the NestJS framework but am stumbling onto an issue. When I try to send out a lot of requests at once the client and receiver become `idle` and wait for about 10 to 15 seconds before proceeding with the pending calls.

I am using the default configuration on both the client and the receiver.

Resources are not the issue, I have a lot of memory and CPU left.
I've tried switching over to Promises over Observables but the issue remains.
From the configurations concerning `keepAlive` I could not find anything which helped out the issue.
When looking at the performance within the debugger both, the receiver and client are within the `idle` state.

The proto file which is used:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package person;

service Greeter {
  rpc GetPerson (PersonSearchByID) returns (PersonResponse);
}

message PersonSearchByID {
  int32 id = 1;
}

message Person {
    string name = 1;
    int32 id = 2;
    string email = 3;
}

message PersonResponse {
  Person person = 1;
}
```

The receiver is the following:

```js
@Controller()
export default class ServerController {
  @GrpcMethod('Greeter', 'GetPerson')
  getPerson(data: aj.PersonSearchByID): aj.PersonResponse {
    console.log(data, Object.getPrototypeOf(data), data.constructor);
    return {
      person: {
        id: data.id,
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'found@me.com',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

The client is the following:

```js
interface GreeterService {
  GetPerson(data: PersonSearchByID): Observable<PersonResponse>;
}

@Controller('client')
export default class ClientController implements OnModuleInit {
  private personService: GreeterService;

  constructor(@Inject('person_package') private readonly client: ClientGrpc) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.personService = this.client.getService<GreeterService>('Greeter');
  }

  @Get()
  public async getClient(
    @Query('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
  ): Promise<PersonResponse> {
    console.log('waiting', id);
    const person = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.personService.GetPerson({ id }).pipe(first()).subscribe(resolve);
    });
    console.log('done', id, person);

    return person;
  }
}
```

And finally the way I'm reaching the freeze state is through the following commands:

```bash
# Parallel requests. Freezes 1 to 2 seconds into the requests.
seq 0 10000 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} curl "localhost:3456/client?id={}" -i -w '\n%{time_total}'

# Sequential. Freezes after ~1300-3000 requests are made
for i in {0..10000}; do curl "localhost:3456/client/test" -i -w '\n%{time_total}'; done
```

For an example of the output:

```
done 7241 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7241, email: 'found@me.com' } }
done 7242 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7242, email: 'found@me.com' } }
done 7243 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7243, email: 'found@me.com' } }
done 7244 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7244, email: 'found@me.com' } }
waiting 7245
waiting 7246
done 7245 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7245, email: 'found@me.com' } }
done 7246 { person: { name: 'John Doe', id: 7246, email: 'found@me.com' } }
waiting 7247
waiting 7248
waiting 7249
waiting 7250
waiting 7251
waiting 7252
waiting 7253
waiting 7254
waiting 7255
waiting 7256 # at this point it freezes for 10 to 15 seconds before receiving more `done` logs
```